# Adding class='active' to parent when child is selected in wp-bootstrap-navwalker

Tags: php, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to add `class='active'` to parent with no success like in this image:

[image]

Right now when I click any child in a dropdown only select the child but no the parent. Any help? [Link to the navwalker here](https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker/blob/master/wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Answering myself. Actually it was a .css matter. The `wp-bootstrap-navwalker` generates many classes that has no style, you have to write rules for them. The walker works perfect out of the box so I used `current-menu-parent`which is a class generated in the active `li ul li`and applied style to it.

Answer (score 0):

I built wp-bootstrap-navwalker and there definitely should be an active class applied to the menu. Are you by chance referring to the parent item when on a sub-menu page?

If you have a link I can probably help you out.